# Mirror API: Not receiving notifications when user selects custom menu item

Tags: google-mirror-api

I'm using the .NET Google Mirror API library for all of this.

I start by inserting a new timeline item which includes the built-in Delete menu item plus a custom menu item:

```
TimelineItem item = new TimelineItem() {
  Text = "Test Item",
  Notification = new NotificationConfig() { Level = "DEFAULT" },
  MenuItems = new List<MenuItem>() {
    new MenuItem() { Action = "DELETE" },
    new MenuItem() { 
      Action = "CUSTOM", 
      Id = "report", 
      Values = new List<MenuValue>() { DisplayName = "Report" }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm also subscribed to timeline notifications, with no Operation specified (so it should receive all operations).  When I select the 'Report' menu item on my Glass, my subscription does not receive a notification.  When I select the 'Delete' menu item on my Glass, my subscription gets a notification for the DELETE, which also includes both the Delete and the Report actions in the UserActions field.

Is there something special I need to do to receive notifications for the custom menu item?

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting built-in menu events such as DELETE, but you are not getting Custom menu events, then your only problem should be handling custom events, not getting them.

To test it;

1. Be sure that you are adding custom menu item to your timelineItem(as
   you shared your code, I see that you are adding it)
2. Subscribe to timeline updates(you wrote that you've subscribed and got DELETE menu event)
3. Add Payload attribute to your custom menu item.
4. At your notifyCallback servlet, handle that Payload value.

This is a `JAVA` code for handling built-in and custom notifications, I guess you can write similar code with `.NET`. Logic is same:

Adding custom menu item:

```
List<MenuValue> menuValues = new ArrayList<MenuValue>();
menuValues.add(new MenuValue().setDisplayName("Test it!"));
menuItemList.add(new MenuItem().setValues(menuValues).setId("MY_CUSTOM_MENU_ITEM_ID").setAction("CUSTOM").setPayload("MY_CUSTOM_MENU_ITEM"));
timelineItem.setMenuItems(menuItemList);
```

Handling custom menu item:

```
// notificationString comes from inputStream of Mirror API's notify request.
Notification notification = jsonFactory.fromString(notificationString, Notification.class);
if (notification.getUserActions().contains(new UserAction().setType("DELETE"))) {
    LOG.info("It was a DELETE of a timeline card.");
} else if (notification.getUserActions().contains(new UserAction().setType("CUSTOM").setPayload("MY_CUSTOM_MENU_ITEM"))) {
    LOG.info("It was a MY_CUSTOM_MENU_ITEM of a timeline card.");
}
```